# Storing HTML / special characters in DB with UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of amending my site to use UTF-8 encoding, this is proving to be a bit of a pain. This is what I have done so far:

1) `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

2) `mysql_set_charset("utf8");`

3) Set the character set of the database, table and column to `utf8`

Now I have some data in a field, the content of which is (the exact form):

`<p>Tom & Jerry £5</p>`

Upon outputting this data to the page, everything appears correct visually. However upon doing a HTML validation check, it fails on the `&` symbol, as it is not being changed to `&amp;`.

Now I tried to fix this by using `htmlentities()` but this encodes everything, including the angle brackets for the HTML `P`tag. So it does not appear correctly. Furthermore the pound symbol appears with a weird character in front of it.

My question is, am I storing the data correctly in the database table? And if so, what do I need to do to ensure everything displays AND validates correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead of [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) when outputting UTF-8 text in a web page.

Comment: If I use `htmlspecialchars`, the HTML tags get encoded too.. so instead of being used to generate the tag, they get displayed on the page.

Comment: The same thing will happen with `htmlentities` anyway. It is probably a storage problem then.

Comment: Hmmm, I may have answered my own question here.. considering the field is storing HTML anyway, why don't I just store special characters in their entity format? I.e. store ampersands as `&amp`. Then I don't need to use `htmlspecialchars` to output it.

Comment: Yeah, your problem is that you're storing invalid HTML (although I think that's permitted in "HTML 5"). `&amp;` (note trailing semi-colon, the omission of which may have just been a typo in your comment.)